# Multiple selection in selenium

Tags: selenium

After entering the name of employee into search box, it has listed 7 names. Out of 7 i do have to select 4 names only.
My following code is selecting the 2 employees from the search result.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver)
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
       .click(employeeList.get(0))
       .click(employeeList.get(4))
       .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
       .build();
       .perform();
```

but when the same code trying to use it with for loop it doesn't selecting all elements.

```
public void selectEmployees() throws Exception {
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    for (int i=0; i<employeeList.size(); i++)  //Employee list is giving the size 7.
    {       
            actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
                   .click(employeeList.get(i))
                   .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
                   .build()
                   .perform();
            }
        }
```

Tried to select all employees with for loop but it has selected 1,3,5,7 record and then deselected 3,5,7 records, only the first remain selected. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend if you haven't tried yet to not build on every iteration of the loop with the same action instance.  Before the for loop, try keying down control just once. Inside the loop, click only the list items your loop iterates through. After the loop, key up control and build the action just once.

It could look like this:

```java
public void selectEmployees() throws Exception {
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL);
    for (int i=0; i<employeeList.size(); i++) {       
        actions.click(employeeList.get(i))
    }
    actions.
        .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
        .build()
        .perform();
}
```

Comment: Yes it has worked as you suggested. Thank you so much.